# Does sound travel through FINGERS?

Tags: solid-state-physics, acoustics, biology, noise, perception

as we know that sound's speed is fastest in solid (and slowest in air).

**QUESTION** - what is the reason when we close our ears and don't really hear loud noises though sound travels faster in solids?

Comment: What is the question here? Are you asking why?

Comment: The down-votes are probably because you haven't explained very clearly what it is that's puzzling you. And the title doesn't seem to fit the subject-matter very well.

Comment: Your new title is spot-on!

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the 'solids' you have in mind are the fingers with which you block the entrances to your ear canals. Two points...

• I don't think the *speed* at which sound travels is, in itself, relevant.

• What 'blocks' most of the sound is reflections that occur at the interface between the outside air and your finger, and at the interface between your finger and the air in the ear canal. A large fraction of the sound energy will be reflected because there will be a big difference in the *acoustic impedances* of air and the material of your fingers.

Answer (score 1):

Well sound travels as a mechanical wave so it disturbs the particle in the surrounding and makes them vibrate at a frequency and this way it reaches the from one place to other.